# r markdown fails to keep the row structure when a list or data.frame is printed

Tags: r, r-markdown

I simply need to display a list or a data frame as is printed in the R console in a markdown latex document but I am having really hard time. I've tried different solutions without any success.

More specifically, I have a dataframe with two columns and I want to print a column based on a condition defined in an ifelse function.

Structure of the data:

```
A tibble: 5 x 2
  `open_pre_What do you think are the positive points o… `open_pre_What do you think are the negative points of this cour…
  <chr>                                                  <chr>                                                            
1 Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated. It was too short and therefore could not unfold it's entirely po…
2 The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic t… The contents were really compact and intensive - sometimes too m…
3 Provided interesting tools.                            Since the course provided interesting and useful tools, the time…
4 Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommo… The time is too limited so that we had to be in a rush to cover …
5 I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do comput… The pace of the exercises on the PC was too fast and hard to fol…
```

Reproducible data

```
structure(list(`open_pre_What do you think are the positive points of this course?` = c("Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated.", 
"The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic to accomplish the goal of the module without making any stragglers.", 
"Provided interesting tools.", "Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommodating TA", 
"I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do computer simulations and modelling."
), `open_pre_What do you think are the negative points of this course, and if applicable, what improvements would you suggest?` = c("It was too short and therefore could not unfold it's entirely potential.", 
"The contents were really compact and intensive - sometimes too much. This course is undoubtedly recommended but it should have more time.", 
"Since the course provided interesting and useful tools, the time was too short to further dig into the details. I.e. a longer course might be helpful.", 
"The time is too limited so that we had to be in a rush to cover everything. More time is a must for next", 
"The pace of the exercises on the PC was too fast and hard to follow. Timing of the classes could also have been better."
)), .Names = c("open_pre_What do you think are the positive points of this course?", 
"open_pre_What do you think are the negative points of this course, and if applicable, what improvements would you suggest?"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

the ifelse function returns the string "no comments" if the list is empty otherwise returns the first columns of the data frame

```
  positive_comments = ifelse(identical(my_data[[1]], character(0))==TRUE,"No Comments",(my_data[1]))
    print(positive_comments[[1]])
```

Output:

```
[1] Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated.
[2] The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic to accomplish the goal of the module without making any stragglers. [3] Provided interesting tools.
[4] Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommodating TA
[5] I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do computer simulations and modelling.
```

As far as I understood this is because the print() command insert line breaks only when needed and for some reasons, in this case, are not.  Note that running the command directly from the console returns the desired outcome

I then tried to convert the list in a data frame but the results are the same.

```
   positive_comments = ifelse(identical(my_data[[1]], character(0))==TRUE,"No Comments",(my_data[1]))
    positive_comments = as.data.frame(positive)
    colnames(positive_comments) <- ""
    print(positive_comments)


print(positive_comments)
```

1 Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated. 2 The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic to accomplish the goal of the module without making any stragglers. 3 Provided interesting tools. 4 Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommodating TA 5 I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do computer simulations and modelling.

```
print(positive_comments[1])
```

1 Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated. 2 The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic to accomplish the goal of the module without making any stragglers. 3 Provided interesting tools. 4 Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommodating TA 5 I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do computer simulations and modelling.

```
print(positive_comments[[1]])
```

[1] Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated.
[2] The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic to accomplish the goal of the module without making any stragglers. [3] Provided interesting tools.
[4] Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommodating TA
[5] I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do computer simulations and modelling.

Lastly, I’ve tried to remove the `results=“asis”` option in the markdown code chunk but it still does not return the desired result. In this case, the print command is allowed to go over the markdown border resulting in an unreadable output. Using `print.data.frame` (or other printing methdos)  **do not** resolve the problem.

**Desired output:**

[1] Very sympathetic and good instructors, very motivated.

[2] The instructor and TA both were really enthusiastic to accomplish the goal of the module without making any stragglers.

[3] Provided interesting tools.

[4] Very interactive and inspiring instructor and accommodating TA

[5] I learnt a lot and got confident that I can do computer simulations and modelling.

Comment: So the first output is right, except that it doesn't break lines? How about `print(strwrap(positive_comments[[1]], 60))`?

Comment: it creates more rows than supposed [link output](https://ibb.co/bBdPvd)

Comment: OK, try `cat(positive_comments[[1]], fill = 60)`. This won't give you numbering; for that you should first insert the numbers explicitly. In general, `cat` is lower level than `print` and gives more control. An alternative approach would be to use (e.g.) my `huxtable` package.

Comment: cat is completely offset in this case. no luck. i am looking into huxtable

Comment: huxtable do not insert line breaks so for long comments it simply goes out of the border. it's not what i am looking for. i need linebreaks

Comment: Perhaps setting `wrap(ht) <- TRUE` will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171106/discussion-between-alberto-stefanelli-and-dash2).